# Subtract SQL DATETIME from datetime.now() in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, strptime

I have a DATETIME field in SQL. Its content is: 2012-08-26 13:00:00

I want to know how much time has passed from that date until now.

In Python 2.7, it's easy:

```
import time,datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-08-26 13:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = start - end
print delta
```

But I have a web server running Python 2.4. In Python 2.4 strptime is not in the datetime module. I can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing in 2.4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[time.strptime](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/module-time.html) is in Python 2.4. It returns a time tuple, which can be then converted to a datetime as shown below.

```
start = time.strptime('2012-08-26 13:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
start = datetime.datetime(*start[:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

in python 2.4, the `strptime()` function is located in the `time` module.